# Image file form uploaded to NextJS middleware API showing request as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

I am using NextJS to process form data and upload to a database but first passing through the NextJS API middleware for editing the image.

### pages/uploadImage.tsx

Client code handler.

```js
...
async function handleImageUpload(imageFile: any): Promise<Response> {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("image", imageFile as File, imageFile.name)
    console.log("FORMDATA: ", formData.getAll("image")) // File object 

    const response: Response = await fetch(`${host}/api/image`, {  // host is localhost:3000  
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })

    return response
  }
...
```

### pages/api/image/index.ts

Middleware/backend for processing image.

```js
export default async function handler({ req, res }: handlerProps) {
  console.log("METHOD: ", req)  // undefined 
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm()

    try {
      form.parse(req, (error: any, fields: any, files: any) => {
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: `${error}` })
        }

        ... handle image and upload to database ...  

        })

        res.status(200).send({ message: "Success" })
      })
    } catch {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Error on processing image" })
    }
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: "POST only supported" })
  }
}
```

Please excuse the messy error handling, I know this isn't good practice.

My issue is at `console.log("METHOD: ", req)  // undefined`.  How is this returning undefined?  Clearly the API route is correct since the code reaches this point but I need help to debug.

I'm thinking my header is wrong in the front end.

I've tried adding to the header, which resulted in the same issue:

```js
 headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
```

I've also tried the JSON in the header with the same result:

```js
const response: Response = await fetch(`${host}/api/image`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay classic syntax mistake.

```js
export default async function handler({ req, res }: handlerProps) {
```

should be

```js
export default async function handler(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse<any>) {
```

where the `req` and `res` are the params and not an object.